# rewrites in nginx when using $map

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy

We are stuck on an issue with rewrites in NGINX we can't figure out.
We are migrating a complicated friendly url redirect system from an old php script that is currently in Apache behind a nginx reverse proxy. We are now trying to move them to the reverse proxy directly so nginx would serve /friendly/parameter/url to whatever php with params.

All nginx recommendations for large list of rewrites recommend the use of maps. We do use them for simple 301 redirects with no issues but when generating them for rewrites (not redirects) the parameters of the destination URLs of the rewrite get encoded and do not work on the destination.

This is:

```
rewrite ~^/holidays/vacations-and-breaks.html$ /scripts/search.php?lang=eng;
```

works fine but:

```
map $old_uri $uri_not_friendly {
   default '';
   ~^/holidays/vacations-and-breaks.html$ /scripts/search.php?lang=eng;
}

if ($uri_not_friendly) {
   rewrite ^ $uri_not_friendly break;
}
```

In the second case the upstream receives the request as:

> /scripts/search.php%3Flang=eng

instead of

> /scripts/search.php?lang=eng

which does not work.

So far we've maintained the rewrites without a map as we understand that map forces the encoding of all parameters and there is no way to avoid that.

Comment: Before I'd answer you question, may I ask some? In what exactly context that `if` block is placed in your configuration? Is it `server` or `location`? Where that `$old_uri` variable come from?

Comment: It's only a sample code not real conf... $old_uri is meant to be the standard requested URI mapped to the servers file that should be returned. thanks